# Convolution and Pooling in TensorFlow Deep MNIST

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

When I study [Deep MNIST for Experts tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/tutorials/mnist/pros/index.html#deep-mnist-for-experts), I have many difficulties.
I'd to know why they used **Convolution and Pooling** in a Multilayer Convolutional Network.

And I don't understand the following two functions.

```
def conv2d(x, W):
return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

def max_pool_2x2(x):
return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                    strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
```

I'd to know the meaning of **strides=[1,1,1,1]** in conv2d function.

Should we always use **ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1]** and **strides=[1, 2, 2, 1]** in max_pool_2x2 function.

What is the difference between **padding='SAME'** and **padding='VALID'**

Comment: I gave a decent description of most of these in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34619177/what-does-tf-nn-conv2d-do-in-tensorflow/34698115#34698115)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between 'SAME' and 'VALID' padding in tf.nn.max\_pool of tensorflow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37674306/what-is-the-difference-between-same-and-valid-padding-in-tf-nn-max-pool-of-t)

Answer (score 1):

I would say check the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34619177/what-does-tf-nn-conv2d-do-in-tensorflow/34698115#34698115). It has a wonderful explanation for the whole convolution operation. This should cover your query for conv2d .

for max pooling,

**ksize**: is basically the kernal size. Its the size of the window for each dimension of the input tensor. you can change it according to your need. Like in the paper [AlexNet](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/4824-imagenet-classification-with-deep-convolutional-neural-networks.pdf) they have used ksize=[1, 3, 3, 1] and

**stride**: The filter is applied to image patches of the same size as the filter and strided according to the strides argument. strides = [1, 2, 2, 1] applies the filter to every other image patch in each dimension, etc.

The difference of padding is explained well in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37674306/what-is-the-difference-between-same-and-valid-padding-in-tf-nn-max-pool-of-t).