# Tensorflow convolutional network - how the dimension (shape) is calculated?

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow

I am not sure how the convolutional neutral network in tensorflow calculates the dimension in this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/tutorials/mnist/pros/index.html#build-a-multilayer-convolutional-network).

1. The image has 28*28 pixels (`x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1,28,28,1])`)
2. The patch size is 5x5 (`W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32]`)
3. The first convolutional layer is done by: (`h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)`)
4. The shape of the first layer is: `h_pool1.get_shape()` and `TensorShape([Dimension(10), Dimension(14), Dimension(14), Dimension(32)])`

**Q1**: Why the first dimension is 10?

**Q2**: Why the 5x5 patch size reduce the dimension to 14x14? If I have a 28x28 image, and I apply 5x5 patch to all pixels, I'd expect more than 14x14.

**Q3**: What's does `-1` do in the code for `x_image`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shapes are (batch_size, height, width, channel).

**Q1.** 10 is your batch size. I guess you have a line like this:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[10, 784])
```

While in the tutorial the line is:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])
```

This way, you will have batchsize "Dimension(None)" instead of "Dimension(10)".

**Q2.**
Layer1 include a convolution layer and a max-pooling layer. The convolution layer with ["SAME" padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37674306/what-is-the-difference-between-same-and-valid-padding-in-tf-nn-max-pool-of-t) will output something with the same size. The size reduction comes from the 2x2 max-pooling with "SAME" padding, which outputs (h/2, w/2).

```
def conv2d(x, W):
   return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

def max_pool_2x2(x):
   return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                         strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)
```

**Q3.**
[tf.reshape() with a single dimension "-1"](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#reshape) leaves the dimension automatically calculated by the program so that the total size remains the same.