# How to do zero padding in keras conv layer?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, padding, conv-neural-network

I am trying to implement model from scientific article, which says they are using zero padding. Is it possible to configure this padding in [keras Conv2D](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#conv2d)?

Only possible values for padding I see are

> padding: one of "valid" or "same" (case-insensitive).

Is it possible to pad with zeros or other constant values?

Comment: Here is more detailed explanation of the keras padding layers https://stackoverflow.com/a/39371113/11239773

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"same" means zero padding. It is currently not possible to pad with other constants in an efficient way.

Comment: How do you know? More probably "same" means padding with the same value, doesn't it?

Comment: The word "Same" refers to the *shape* of the result, not its values. That is, the returned tensor has the same shape as the input.

Comment: It appears that "same" does not work the same way as when using "valid" with a preceding ZeroPadding2D layer. Please check my experiment here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60323897/tensorflow-keras-conv2d-layers-with-padding-same-behave-strangely

Answer (score 8):

When you use `padding='valid'`, there's no padding.

When you use `padding='same'` with `strides=1`, the input are zero-padded so that width and height of output is the same as the input. As described in the document, "same" is slightly inconsistent across backends with `strides` != 1.

If you want to **manually** set the padding value, maybe the simplest way is to add a [`ZeroPadding2D`](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#zeropadding2d) layer before `Conv2D`.

For example, `ZeroPadding2D(padding=((1,2),(3,4)))` will add 1 dimension on the left, 2 on the right, 3 on the top and 4 on the bottom. `ZeroPadding2D(5)` will add 5 dimension on all 4 borders.

(btw, It's a wrap layer of backend function `spatial_2d_padding`)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [`spatial_2d_padding`](https://keras.io/backend/#spatial_2d_padding) function. It pads a tensor with zeroes.

Comment: Indeed. This is ideal for cases where you want a non-standard padding. A convolutional layer has the `padding='same'` option that will automatically pad with zeros to keep the same shape as the input. But if you want something that is not provided by the convolutional layer itself, or in other cases, this is the right function to go.

Comment: Example of usage?

Answer (score 1):

https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/

ZeroPadding2D=>

keras.layers.ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1, 1), data_format=None)
Zero-padding layer for 2D input (e.g. picture).

This layer can add rows and columns of zeros at the top, bottom, left and right side of an image tensor.

Arguments

padding: int, or tuple of 2 ints, or tuple of 2 tuples of 2 ints.
If int: the same symmetric padding is applied to height and width.
If tuple of 2 ints: interpreted as two different symmetric padding values for height and width: (symmetric_height_pad, symmetric_width_pad).
If tuple of 2 tuples of 2 ints: interpreted as  ((top_pad, bottom_pad), (left_pad, right_pad))

data_format: A string, one of "channels_last" or "channels_first". The ordering of the dimensions in the inputs.  "channels_last" corresponds to inputs with shape  (batch, height, width, channels) while "channels_first" corresponds to inputs with shape  (batch, channels, height, width). It defaults to the image_data_format value found in your Keras config file at ~/.keras/keras.json. If you never set it, then it will be "channels_last".

Answer (score 0):

I think padding='same' means that in case we are in a hidden layer the empty cells that the stride find will be filled with the values of the previous layer not with zeros, only if is the input layer will be filled with zeros.