# Tensorflow/Keras Conv2D layers with padding='SAME' behave strangely

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, zero-padding

**My question:**

A straightforward experiment that I conducted showed that using `padding='SAME'` in a conv2d layer in Keras/TF is different from using `padding='VALID'` with a preceding zero-padding layer.

1. How is that possible?
2. Does Keras/TF pads zeros symmetrically around the tensor?

**Explanation of the experiment - just if you're interested in reading further:**

I used the `onnx2keras` package to convert my Pytorch model into keras/TF.

When `onnx2keras` encounters a convolutional layer with `padding > 0` in the ONNX model, it translates it to Keras' `Conv2D` with `valid` padding (i.e., no padding!), preceded by Keras' `ZeroPadding2D` layer. This works very well and returns outputs that are identical to those produced by the Pytorch network.

I yet thought it was strange that it didn't simply used `padding='SAME'`, as most of the references say that Keras/TF use zero padding, just like Pytorch does.

Nevertheless, I patched `onnx2keras` and made it produce me `Conv2D` layers with `padding='SAME'` rather than the existing solution of `'VALID'` padding with a preceding zero-padding layer. This made the resulting model return different outputs than the one with the zero-padding layer, and of course different from my Pytorch model, which was identical until the patch.

Comment: as per the [documentation](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/) "valid" is no padding while "same"  results in padding the input such that the output has the same length as the original input.

Comment: @nickthefreak of course. But I expected "same" to work the same way as when manually adding a padding layer before the convolution and then using "valid", but this is not what happens

Comment: @SomethingSomething -  It will be clear to explain or identify the error if you post the simple reproducible code that you experimented.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`padding='Same'` in Keras means padding is added as required to make up for overlaps when the input size and kernel size do not perfectly fit.

**Example of padding='Same':**

```
# Importing dependency
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D

# Create a sequential model
model = Sequential()

# Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=24, input_shape=(5,5,1), kernel_size=(2,2), strides =(2,2) ,padding='Same'))

# Model Summary
model.summary()
```

**Output of the code -**

```
Model: "sequential_20"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_28 (Conv2D)           (None, 3, 3, 24)          120       
=================================================================
Total params: 120
Trainable params: 120
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

**Pictorial Representation:**
Below image shows how the padding for the input (input_shape=(5,5,1), kernel_size=(2,2), strides =(2,2)) when padding='Same'.

[image]

### ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

`padding='Valid'` in Keras means no padding is added.

**Example of padding='Valid':** Have used same input for Conv2D that we used above for padding = 'Same' .i.e. (input_shape=(5,5,1), kernel_size=(2,2), strides =(2,2))

```
# Importing dependency
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D

# Create a sequential model
model = Sequential()

# Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=24, input_shape=(5,5,1), kernel_size=(2,2), strides =(2,2) ,padding='Valid'))

# Model Summary
model.summary()
```

**Output of the code -**

```
Model: "sequential_21"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_29 (Conv2D)           (None, 2, 2, 24)          120       
=================================================================
Total params: 120
Trainable params: 120
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

**Pictorial Representation:**
Below image shows there is no padding added for the input (input_shape=(5,5,1), kernel_size=(2,2), strides =(2,2)) when padding='Valid'.
[image]

### ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Now lets try same code that we used for `padding='Valid'` for the input (input_shape=(6,6,1), kernel_size=(2,2), strides =(2,2)). **Here `padding='Valid'` should behave same as `padding='Same'`.**

**Code -**

```
# Importing dependency
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D

# Create a sequential model
model = Sequential()

# Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=24, input_shape=(6,6,1), kernel_size=(2,2), strides =(2,2) ,padding='Valid'))

# Model Summary
model.summary()
```

**Output of the code -**

```
Model: "sequential_22"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_30 (Conv2D)           (None, 3, 3, 24)          120       
=================================================================
Total params: 120
Trainable params: 120
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the very detailed answer. So if I understood correctly from the first figure, the padding in TF is done by duplicating the right and bottom vectors?

Comment: Yes. You are correct. The padding='Same' results in padding the input such that the kernel covers all the pixel for the input_shape=(5,5,1) with Stride=(2,2).  If Stride=(1,1) then, padding='Same' results in padding the input such that the output has the same length as the original input.

Comment: Good to know. This is in contradiction to PyTorch, which pads with zeros from all the sides. This is the reason why `onnx2keras` translates a conv2d layer with padding into two different layers in TF - first a zero padding layer and then a "valid" conv2d layer