# which value is used for padding in tensorflow convolution?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pytorch, convolution

In **PyTorch**, there are two choices for `padding_mode` when using convolution: *zeros* and *circular*.

However, I cannot find a similar parameter in the docs of **TensorFlow**.

In addition, I find that TensorFlow is not using `0` as the value to pad the inputs.

Does anyone know the answer?

Comment: Have you seen this question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45013060/how-to-do-zero-padding-in-keras-conv-layer

Answer (score 0):

It *does* use zeros:

```
import tensorflow as tf

inputs = tf.ones((1, 10, 1))
```

Imagine strides of 2 with a filter of 3 (made only of 1s)

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 10, 1), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[1.],  |
        [1.],  | 3  
        [1.],  |   |          
        [1.],      | 3      
        [1.],      |    |  
        [1.],           | 3  
        [1.],           |    | 
        [1.],                | 3           
        [1.],                |    |
        [1.]                      | 2
        # (will add a zero here)
]], dtype=float32)>
```

All the elements from the operation will result in `sum(1, 1, 1)`. If the last one is padded with zeros, the result will be `sum(1, 1, 0)`, which it is:

```
conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=1,
                              kernel_size=3,
                              strides=2,
                              padding='SAME',
                              kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Ones)

tf.squeeze(conv(inputs))
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(5,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([3., 3., 3., 3., 2.], dtype=float32)>
```

You can also see/demonstrate this using [`tf.nn.conv1d`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv1d):

```
import tensorflow as tf

inputs = tf.ones((1, 10, 1))

result = tf.nn.conv1d(input=inputs,
                      filters=tf.ones((3, 1, 1)),
                      stride=2,
                      padding='SAME')

tf.squeeze(result)
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(5,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([3., 3., 3., 3., 2.], dtype=float32)>
```