# How does tensorflow connect the dimensions of linked convolutional layers?

Tags: python, tensorflow

The is a very basic tensorflow question, but I haven't yet seen a clear explanation in the docs.  Following the [examples on the tensorflow site](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers), we basically have these two layers connected:

```
conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(
    inputs=input_layer,
    filters=32,
    kernel_size=[5, 5],
    padding="same",
    activation=tf.nn.relu)
```

The shape at this point will be `(28, 28, 32)`.

```
conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(
    inputs=conv1,
    filters=64,
    kernel_size=[5, 5],
    padding="same",
    activation=tf.nn.relu)
```

The shape at this point will be `(28, 28, 64)`.  How does tensorflow take the `(28, 28, 32)` and turn it into `(28, 28, 64)` using a 2d kernel.  Could you please explain or point me to the documentation?  How about when the output dimension of the second layer is smaller, say

```
conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(
    inputs=conv1,
    filters=8,
    kernel_size=[5, 5],
    padding="same",
    activation=tf.nn.relu)
```

How would tensorflow combine the 32 dimensions into 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have 1 filter (=channel) in the input and the output as well, you will get one 5x5 convolution kernel, which is used to calculate the output for pixel ***(x, y)*** by taking the Hadamard (element-wise) product of the kernel and ***input[ x - 2 : x + 3, y - 2 : y + 3 ]*** and then taking the sum of the resulting 5x5 matrix, finally applying the *activation function* ( [`tf.nn.relu()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/relu) in your case.) Since some of these coordinates point outside of the input, then the [`padding="SAME"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37674306/what-is-the-difference-between-same-and-valid-padding-in-tf-nn-max-pool-of-t/44102413#44102413) comes into play and zero is used as a virtual element for outside positions for the sake of this calculation. Your network will learn the weights in the kernel.

Now let's suppose you have 2 filters in the input and 1 in the output. Then you have *two* kernels, and the output will be the *sum* of the result of the two separate operations described above applied to each input channel.

If you have 1 filters in the input and 2 in the output, then again, you have *two* kernels, and the two output channels for each pixel will be generated separately with the use of the corresponding kernels.

Now the big jump: if you have ***k*** filters in the input and ***n*** filters in the output, then you have ***( k * n )*** different kernels to learn, and each of the ***n*** channels for each pixel in the output will be calculated as the sum of ***k*** separate convolutions on each input channel. All ***( k * n )*** kernels will be learned by the network.

Comment: Thanks Peter!  Very clear and helps elucidate the mechanics.