# What's the difference between conv2d(SAME) and tf.pad + conv2d(VALID)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm almost new to `tensorflow`, and when I learn `tensorflow` through some tutorials, i've read the following codes:

```
if stride == 1:
    return slim.conv2d(inputs, num_outputs, kernel_size, stride=1, padding='SAME', scope=scope)
else:
    pad_total = kernel_size - 1
    pad_beg = pad_total // 2
    pad_end = pad_total - pad_beg
    inputs = tf.pad(inputs, [[0, 0], [pad_beg, pad_end], [pad_beg, pad_end], [0, 0]])
    return slim.conv2d(inputs, num_outputs, kernel_size, stride=stride, padding='VALID', scope=scope)
```

However, i also learn that, "SAME" padding means the output data has the same size with the input data, while "VALID" means different, and the the method of `tf.pad` also pad zero manually, so is there any difference between these two methods? Or what's the purpose of this `tf.pad`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between 'SAME' and 'VALID' padding in tf.nn.max\_pool of tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37674306/what-is-the-difference-between-same-and-valid-padding-in-tf-nn-max-pool-of-t)

Comment: Not a duplicate, since it specifically asks whether the manually padding the image is different, whereas the "duplicate question" only considers the differences in padding for this image.
As far as I read from the definitions, you should be correct in your question, i.e. the two should produce the same results. the `pad` method still has its validity, since you could essentially pad with *any arbitrary value*, whereas `SAME` will use zeros every time.

Comment: Note that manual padding gives you slightly more control: In case of even filter size there needs to uneven padding, and the conv functions with "same" padding will (IIRC) always pad one more at the _end_ (right/bottom) whereas you might want to have it the other way around for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

In many real-word use-cases, there is no difference.

For instance, in some imagenet architectures, we often pad with 1, then do a 3x3 convolution. Behaviour of the network would be the same if you first zero-pad with 1, then convolve, or if you convolve with "same" padding.

However, behaviour will be different in non-standard situations. Remember that you can define kernel size AND stride AND dilation rate at a convolution layer.

A counterexample where there is a difference between conv2d(SAM) and a **symmetric tf.pad** +conv2d(VALID):

Input: (7,7,1)
Kernel: (4,4)
Stride: (2,2)

conv2d(SAME) here would be the same as tf.pad(0 pixel left/top, 1 pixel right/bottom), and would yield a (3,3,1) output.