# Keras Functional API: Pooling input does not give correct output shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am learning Keras with Tensorflow and I build as very simple model which takes input image of size`224x224x3` and applies `MaxPooling`, flatten it into 1D vector and this 1D vector is the output.

Please note that, this model is just purely for tutorial purpose. However, when I see the summary of the model i.e., `model.summary()` the output of the pooling layer is of same size as the input.

Code:

```
    in_shape = (224, 224, 3)
    in_feats = Input(shape=in_shape)
    pool = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=4, strides=1, padding='same')(in_feats)
    flat = Flatten(name='flat')(pool)
    model = Model(inputs=in_feats, outputs=flat)
    # print summary
    print (model.summary())
```

The summary is as follows:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 224, 224, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
pool (MaxPooling2D)          (None, 224, 224, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
flat (Flatten)               (None, 150528)            0         
=================================================================
Total params: 0
Trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

As you will notice the output from the pooling layer is same size as the input. What may be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

It was a silly mistake. It result depends on the padding type used with the pooling layer.
The following gives the correct result.

```
pool = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=4, strides=1, padding='valid')(in_feats)
```

You can read more about the padding [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37674306/what-is-the-difference-between-same-and-valid-padding-in-tf-nn-max-pool-of-t)