# How does tf.keras.layers.Conv2D with padding='same' and strides > 1 behave?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I read [What is the difference between 'SAME' and 'VALID' padding in tf.nn.max_pool of tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37674306/what-is-the-difference-between-same-and-valid-padding-in-tf-nn-max-pool-of-t/39371113#39371113) but this is not true to my experiment.

```
import tensorflow as tf

inputs = tf.random_normal([1, 64, 64, 3])
print(inputs.shape)
conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(6, 4, strides=2, padding='same')
outputs = conv(inputs)
print(outputs.shape)
```

produces

```
(1, 64, 64, 3)
(1, 32, 32, 6)
```

. However following the above link produces `(1, 31, 31, 6)` because  there is no extra values outside filter ranges without any padding.

How does tf.keras.layers.Conv2D with padding='same' and strides > 1 behave?
I want to know the exact answer and its evidence.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Keras uses TensorFlow implementation of padding. All the details are available in the documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/convolution)

> First, consider the 'SAME' padding scheme. A detailed explanation of
> the reasoning behind it is given in [these notes](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/convolution). Here, we summarize
> the mechanics of this padding scheme. When using 'SAME', the output
> height and width are computed as:
>
> ```
> out_height = ceil(float(in_height) / float(strides[1]))
> out_width  = ceil(float(in_width) / float(strides[2]))
> ```
>
> The total padding applied along the height and width is computed as:
>
> ```
> if (in_height % strides[1] == 0):
>   pad_along_height = max(filter_height - strides[1], 0)
> else:
>   pad_along_height = max(filter_height - (in_height % strides[1]), 0)
> if (in_width % strides[2] == 0):
>   pad_along_width = max(filter_width - strides[2], 0)
> else:
>   pad_along_width = max(filter_width - (in_width % strides[2]), 0)
> ```
>
> Finally, the padding on the top, bottom, left and right are:
>
> ```
> pad_top = pad_along_height // 2
> pad_bottom = pad_along_height - pad_top
> pad_left = pad_along_width // 2
> pad_right = pad_along_width - pad_left
> ```
>
> Note that the division by 2 means that there might be cases when the
> padding on both sides (top vs bottom, right vs left) are off by one.
> In this case, the bottom and right sides always get the one additional
> padded pixel. For example, when pad_along_height is 5, we pad 2 pixels
> at the top and 3 pixels at the bottom. Note that this is different
> from existing libraries such as cuDNN and Caffe, which explicitly
> specify the number of padded pixels and always pad the same number of
> pixels on both sides.
>
> For the 'VALID' scheme, the output height and width are computed as:
>
> ```
> out_height = ceil(float(in_height - filter_height + 1) / float(strides[1]))
> out_width  = ceil(float(in_width - filter_width + 1) / float(strides[2]))
> ```
>
> and no padding is used.

Comment: Links no longer working. See https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.12/api_guides/python/nn instead.

Answer (score 3):

In tensorflow, for stride `s` and input size `n`, padding with same gives:

⌈n/s⌉

or the ceiling of input size divided by stride.