# Using conv2d in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to use conv2d in tensorflow, The code as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
filter_num = 3
filter_size = 5
char_embed_size = 300
max_word_length = 1
max_seq_length = 15
embeddings = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([512,14,300]))
#cnn_inputs = tf.reshape(word_embeddings, (-1, max_word_length, char_embed_size, 1))
cnn_inputs = tf.reshape(embeddings, (-1, max_word_length, char_embed_size, 1))
filter_shape = [filter_size, char_embed_size, 1, filter_num]
w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(filter_shape, stddev=0.1), name="cnn_w")
b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[filter_num]), name="cnn_b")
conv = tf.nn.conv2d(
    cnn_inputs,
    w,
    strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
    padding="VALID")
```

when I run it,it occurs the errors as follows:

> ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 5 from 1
>   for   'Conv2D' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [7168,1,300,1],
>   [5,300,1,3]

It seems the input shape does not match, how do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR answer.**

Use padding="SAME":

```
conv = tf.nn.conv2d(
    cnn_inputs,
    w,
    strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
    padding="SAME") # old value is padding="VALID"
```

**Detailed answer.**

According to TF documentation input tensor (`cnn_inputs`) should be of shape `[batch, in_height, in_width, in_channels]` and kernel tensor (`w` in your example) should be of shape `[filter_height, filter_width, in_channels, out_channels]`

In your sample:

- `cnn_input.shape` is `[7168, 1, 300, 1]` therefore `in_height == 1` and `in_width = 300`
- `w.shape` is `[5, 300, 1, 3]`, therefore `filter_height == 5` and `filter_width == 300`

If `padding="VALID"` and `stride=[1, 1, 1, 1]` then conv2d operation will "shrink" input tensor in spatial dimension by substracting `filter_size` in spatial dimension. For example if  `in_height == 20`, and `filter_height == 4` then output tensor height would probably be 20 - 4 = 16. In your sample with `in_height == 1` and `filter_height == 5` the shape of output tensor along the height dimension is approximately `in_height - filter_height = 1 - 5 = -4`, i.e. you recieve tensor with negative height which is not possible and that causes the error.

With `padding="SAME"` the conv2d operation tries to preserve spatial dimensions by adding zero values (the process is called "zero padding"). Therefore the height of output tensor stays the same with `in_height`

You can find more detailed explanation for `padding` here: [What is the difference between 'SAME' and 'VALID' padding in tf.nn.max_pool of tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37674306/what-is-the-difference-between-same-and-valid-padding-in-tf-nn-max-pool-of-t)