# How is uneven input handled with same average pooling in keras / tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, max-pooling

Very similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37674306/what-is-the-difference-between-same-and-valid-padding-in-tf-nn-max-pool-of-t) but for average pooling.

The accpeted answer says, that same pooling uses -inf as padding for maxpooling.
But what is used for average pooling. 
Do they use just 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I just testef it out myself.

```
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.nan)
x = np.array([[[3.0,3.0,3.0],[3.0,3.0,3.0]]])
x = x.reshape(1,2,3,1)
sess = tf.Session()
K.set_session(sess)
b = K.constant(x)
b = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), padding="same")(b)
b = tf.Print(b,[b])
sess.run(b)
```

This returns the tensor [[[[3][3]]]] so it has to pad with 0.