# How does tf.nn.conv2d behave with an even-sized filter?

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34619177/what-does-tf-nn-conv2d-do-in-tensorflow) for which the accepted answer only mentions square odd-sized filters (1x1, 3x3), and I am intrigued about how `tf.nn.conv2d()` behaves when using a square even-sized filter (e.g. 2x2) given that none of its elements can be considered its centre.

If `padding='VALID'` then I assume that `tf.nn.conv2d()` will *stride* across the input in the same way as it would if the filter were odd-sized.

However, if `padding='SAME'` how does `tf.nn.conv2d()` choose to centre the even-sized filter over the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the description here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/nn.html#convolution

For VALID padding, you're exactly right. You simply walk the filter over the input without any padding, moving the filter by the stride each time.

For SAME padding, you do the same as VALID padding, but conceptually you pad the input with some zeros before and after each dimension before computing the convolution. If an odd number of padding elements must be added, the right/bottom side gets the extra element.

Use the formula `pad_...` formulae in the link above to work out how much padding to add. For example, for simplicity, let's consider a 1D convolution. For a input of size 7, a window of size 2, and a stride of 1, you would add 1 element of padding to the right, and 0 elements of padding to the left.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

when you do filtering in the conv layer, you simply getting the mean of each patch:

taking example of 1D size 5 input [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ],
use size 2 filter and do valid padding, stride is 1,
you will get size 4 output（use mean of the inner product for weight parameter metrix of [1,1])  [ (1+2)/2, (2+3)/2, (3+4)/2, (4+5)/2 ], 
which is [ 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5 ],

if you do same padding with stride 1, you will get size 5 output [ (1+2)/2, (2+3)/2, (3+4)/2, (4+5)/2, (5 + 0)/2 ], the final 0 here is the padding 0, 
which is [ 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 2.5 ],

vise versa,  if you have a 224*224 input, when you do 2 by 2 filtering using valid padding, it will out put 223*223 output