# How a filter in convolutional neural network can generate multiple channels?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I am learning convolutional neural network with Tensorflow.

I have some doubts regarding [`tf.nn.conv2d`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d). One of its parameters is `filter`:

> a filter / kernel tensor of shape [filter_height, filter_width,  in_channels, out_channels]

I do not understand what is the meaning of `out_channels`.

Suppose input image is `[1, 3, 3, 1]`. So the size is 3xx and the channel is 1.
Then we have a filter `[2, 2, 1, 5]`, which means after the filtering, we will have an image of size 2x2 ("valid" padding) with 5 channels.

Where are the 5 channels from? From my understanding, the filtering can only have 1 channel generated. Is Tensorflow using 5 different filter functions here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34619177/what-does-tf-nn-conv2d-do-in-tensorflow

Comment: Not duplicate. I am asking different question.It is a comment of that thread: Regarding this: "This still gives a 5x5 output image, but with 7 channels (size 1x5x5x7). Where each channel is produced by one of the filters in the set.", I still have difficulty understanding where the 7 channels are from? what do you mean "filters in the set"? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `filter` argument to the [`tf.nn.conv2d`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d) function, as you quoted, is a 4D tensor of dimensions `[filter_height, filter_width, in_channels, out_channels]`. This tensor represents a stack of `out_channels` filters of dimension `filter_height x filter_width`, to be applied over an image with `in_channels` channels.

The parameters, `filter_height`, `filter_width` and `out_channels` are *defined by you*, whereas `input_channels` is dependent on your input to `tf.nn.conv2d`.

In other words, a filter tensor with dimensions `[2, 2, 1, 5]`, represents `5` different `2 x 2` filters to be applied over a `1`-channel input, but you could perfectly change it to `[2, 2, 1, 7]`, or whatever else gives you better results.

To further illustrate, in the following gif you have a `[3, 3, 1, 1]` tensor filter convolving over a `[1, 5, 5, 1]` image. This means you have only `1` filter being convolved over the image.

[image: Convolution GIF]

[GIF source](http://deeplearning.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Feature_extraction_using_convolution)

Comment: You should add reference for using the gif animation.

Comment: With your GIF example, what is output of [3,3,1,2] filter?

Comment: That would be a `[1, 3, 3, 2]` convolved feature, equivalent to a `3 x 3` image with `2` channels.  However the GIF example is just an illustration since it doesn't include any kind of padding. If you want a consistent way of determining the output size of a convolution you should check the `(W - F + 2P) / S + 1` formula explained in [Stanford's CNN course](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/).

Comment: with the current filter matrix specified in your GIF example, you can have a convolved feature containing one channel/layer as shown in your GIF example. So now let us say we change the filter to [3,3,1,2] which implies there will be 2 out_channels, i.e., the convolved feature will have two layers/channels. In this case, does that mean we will have another filter  matrix different from the one specified in your GIF example?

Comment: Do you get "out_channels" number of channels no matter the original number of channels? Or are they multiplied?