# don't understand mnist example in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I don't understand the mnist example in 'deep mnist for experts' in Tensorflow.

In order to build a deep network, we stack several layers of this type. The second layer will have 64 features for each 5x5 patch.

```
W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])

h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)
```

I don't know why outputchannel is 64.

I think we need to 32*2 * 5*5 filter for 64 outputchannel, so

```
W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 2])
```

---

first of all, i'm sorry for not good english
maybe you hard to understand my ask
so i', write sudo code logic

```
inputimage = arr[1][28][28][32]
w_conv2 = arr[5][5][32][2]
output = [1][28][28][64]
for batch in 1
  for input in 32
    for output in 2
        output[][][][input*output] = conv(inputimage,w_conv2)
```

i think it make 62 output feature using 32*2 filter and save memory
what part is wrong?

thank you

Comment: Look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42507766/why-am-i-getting-only-one-channeled-output-through-the-tf-nn-conv2d) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34619177/what-does-tf-nn-conv2d-do-in-tensorflow) and you'll get your answer.

Comment: first of all, i'm sorry for not good english
maybe you hard to understand my ask
so i', write sudo code logic 

inputimage = arr[1][28][28][32]

w_conv2 = arr[5][5][32][2]

output = [1][28][28][64]

for batch in 1
 for input in 32
  for output in 2
   output[][][][input*output] = conv(inputimage,w_conv2)

i think it make 62 output feature using 32*2 filter and save memory
what part is wrong?

thank you

Comment: You can also look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42451067/3941813), to a very similar question.

Comment: in your answer,  are the number of features  (in_channels * out_channels) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact is that the output dimension is independent from that of the input.

In fact each step of the convolution is a tensor product between W_conv2 (W) and any `(n * m)` portion of the input matrix (I): if W has dimension `(n * m * k * h)` and I `(n * m * k)`, the result of the product I*W is a vector with dimension `h`.

`n, m, and k` must be equal in I and W, but you don't have any limitation on `h`.

Answer (score 0):

It's bigger because you are using your filter(5x5) and using it on every filter for every inputdata. So it would look like:
32*2*1 (one because you are using one filter)