# How to specify filter in keras conv2d

Tags: python, filter, keras, convolution, keras-layer

I am trying to implement into my Keras model a conv2D layer that uses a specific Gaussian filter. I have code that makes the filter, although the existing [Keras Conv2D](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/) does not have a parameter for the filter itself. Instead, there is a `filters` parameter, which is an integer that specifies the dimensionality of the output space, and the `kernel_size`, which is a tuple that specifies the dimensions of the kernel.

I have tried to use the Keras backend stuff to solve this problem, as the conv2D function [here](https://keras.io/backend/#using-the-abstract-keras-backend-to-write-new-code) allows you to input a specific filter as I would like to do. The problem is that I do not know how to get this back into my model, so again, I am stuck. I have also found questions similar to mine like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44410135/keras-conv2d-own-filters) one which suggests writing my own layer, but I am not really sure how I would go about doing that, and would hope to avoid it if there is an easier way.

As always, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a way to handle it? I have a similar use case. I need to use Gaussian and gaussian derivative filters in my 1st CNN layer and learn some linear combinations of them. But I am not sure how to introduce the Gaussians in my 1st layer.

Answer (score 2):

**Long answer short:**

**You don't need a convolution layer at all**.

The purpose of convolution layers is **to find the right filters for you**. As you already know which filter to use, you can happily skip the whole convolution stuff and jump straight to the fully connected layers.

1. Apply the Gaussian filters to your image.
2. Use the **Flatten()** layer to feed the images directly to a MLP.

Hope this help.

Comment: What procedure uses conv2D to find the proper filter?
For example, if you say filters=1 what filter uses? vertical, horizontal...?

Answer (score 1):

I have just posted an answer to the [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44410135/keras-conv2d-own-filters) question but it may be useful here as an example of how to apply a custom filter in Keras. For your example of a Gaussian, use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29731726/how-to-calculate-a-gaussian-kernel-matrix-efficiently-in-numpy) adapted for 2D to get a filter,

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st

def gkern(kernlen=[21,21], nsig=[3, 3]):
    """Returns a 2D Gaussian kernel array."""

    assert len(nsig) == 2
    assert len(kernlen) == 2
    kern1d = []
    for i in range(2):
        interval = (2*nsig[i]+1.)/(kernlen[i])
        x = np.linspace(-nsig[i]-interval/2., nsig[i]+interval/2., kernlen[i]+1)
        kern1d.append(np.diff(st.norm.cdf(x)))

    kernel_raw = np.sqrt(np.outer(kern1d[0], kern1d[1]))
    kernel = kernel_raw/kernel_raw.sum()
    return kernel

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(gkern([7,7]), interpolation='none')
plt.show()
```

You can then set this as an initial filter and freeze that layer so it no longer trains, which would look something like this,

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D

#Set Some Image
image = [[4,3,1,0],[2,1,0,1],[1,2,4,1],[3,1,0,2]]

# Pad to "channels_last" format 
# which is [batch, width, height, channels]=[1,4,4,1]
image = np.expand_dims(np.expand_dims(np.array(image),2),0)

#Initialise to set kernel to required value
def kernel_init(shape):
    kernel = np.zeros(shape)
    kernel[:,:,0,0] = gkern([shape[0], shape[1]])
    return kernel 

#Build Keras model
model = Sequential()
#We would freeze training of the layers if we
# wanted to keep a Gaussian filter
Gausslayer = Conv2D(1, [3,3], kernel_initializer=kernel_init, 
                    input_shape=(4,4,1), padding="valid")
Gausslayer.trainable = False
model.add(Gausslayer)
#Add some more layers here
#model.add(Conv2D(...)
model.build()

# To apply existing filter, we use predict with no training
out = model.predict(image)
print(out[0,:,:,0])
```

and can be adapted to add more layers which are trainable.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gkern.py", line 48, in <module>
    model.add(Gausslayer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 517, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 208, in add
    layer(x)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 946, in __call__
    return self._functional_construction_call(inputs, args, kwargs,