# How to initialize a Conv2D layer with predetermined list of kernels in tensorflow/keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, convolution

I would like to use `Conv2D` layer in order to stride an input image and run three `2x2` kernels.

This is not the purpose of tensorflow, but I really want to use tensorflow as the  backend engine to run kernels efficiently and to distribute the work load between different devices GPUs and/or CPUs.

I tried something like the following code. But It doesn't seem to work very well.

```
import tensorflow as tf

class InitConvKernels(tf.keras.initializers.Initializer):

  def __init__(self, num_kernels, kernel_tensor):
    self.kernel_list= kernel_tensor
    self.index = -1
    self.num_kernels = num_kernels

  def __call__(self, shape, dtype=None):
    index += 1 
    assert(self.index <= self.num_kernels) # doesn't affect anything
    tf.print(shape) # doesn't work
    return self.kernel_list[index]

  def get_config(self):
    return {'kernel_list': self.kernel_list, 'num_kernels': self.num_kernels}
```

I am calling the custom initializer, but the returned layer is empty:

```
kernel_list = tf.constant([[[-1, -1],  [-1, -1]], [[1, 1],   [1, 1]],  [[-1, 1],  [1, -1]],])
layer = layers.Conv2D(
    filters=3,
    kernel_size=2,
    kernel_initializer=InitConvKernels(3,kernel_list),
    bias_initializer=initializers.Zeros()
)
```

`layer.variables` is empty (`[]`)
`layer.layer.get_weights()` is also empty (`[]`)

My goal is to evaluate the convolution of the three kernels in `kernel_list` on an input image and aggregate all the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from PIL import Image
import requests
from io import BytesIO
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D


response = requests.get('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/02/Stack_Overflow_logo.svg/1280px-Stack_Overflow_logo.svg.png')
image = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
```

Loading an [image from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391945/how-do-i-read-image-data-from-a-url-in-python).
[image]

Build a model to run a [kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44410135/keras-conv2d-own-filters) (to run more kernels make `kernel_init` a generator and readily adjust the number of filters when initializing `Conv2D`)

```
def kernel_init(shape, dtype=None, partition_info=None):
    kernel = np.zeros(shape)
    kernel[:,:,0,0] = np.array([[1,0,1],[-1,0,-1],[1,0,1]])
    return kernel

#Build Keras model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(1, [3,3], kernel_initializer=kernel_init, 
                 input_shape=(251,1280,4), padding="valid"))
model.build()

# To apply existing filter, we use predict with no training
out = model.predict(image)
```

And visualizing the output:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.matshow(out[0,:,:,0])
```

[image]

Edit:
It's worth mentioning [OpenAI's Triton](https://www.openai.com/blog/triton/) which can help using higher level language and framework such as pytorch to run efficient GPU code:

> Python-like programming language which enables researchers with no
> CUDA experience to write highly efficient GPU code—most of the time on
> par with what an expert would be able to produce.

Comment: Note that you can simply use `tf.nn.conv2d`, which accepts a 4d kernel tensor/array as input directly.