# What are channels in tf.nn.conv2D?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I've looked through some [great explanations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34619177/what-does-tf-nn-conv2d-do-in-tensorflow) on what different arguments of tf.nn.conv2D represent, but I still can't understand what exactly in_channels and out_channels represent.

Could someone please clarify this for me?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Lets say you have a image of size `64x64`. It is composed of `R-G-B` of `64x64` each, so the input size is `64x64x3` and `3` is the input channel in this case. Now you want to convolve this input with a `kernel` of `5x5x3`, you get an output of `64x64x1` (with padding). Suppose you have `100` such kernels and convolve each one of them with the input, you get `64x64x100`. Here the output channels are `100`.

Comment: sir , How we decide the no of  filter output channels?

Comment: It's a hyperparameter,you need to fine tune, a smaller value may cause  under fitting, while a larger value  may over fit the data.

Comment: I felt that the number of output channels is just the same as the number of kernels in this case. Is this correct? And may I also wonder why do we have output of `64*64*1` for the output after applying a kernel of `5*5*3`? Thanks.