# how to merge 'Conv-BN-Scale' into a single 'Conv' layer for tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

For faster inference one model, I want to merge '`Conv-BN-Scale`' into a single '`Conv`' layer for my tensorflow model, **but I can not find some useful complete example about how to do it**?
**Anyone can give some advises or complete code example?**

*Thanks!*

Comment: I am not sure about your question, but you can always write a Python class called something like MyLayer and define whatever order of operations you'd like to have.

Comment: @Richard_wth thanks your reply, can you provide some complete example code?

Comment: I understand conv is convolution, BN is batch normalization, but by scale do you mean activation like ReLU or something else?

Comment: @anand_v.singh thanks for your comment, scale means `beta` and `gamma` of `batch normalization`. Please refer to https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/batch_normalization

Comment: @RayTing So basically you want a function that performs convolution `tf.nn.conv2d()` and `tf.layers.batch_normalization()` together and want to pass the parameters for `tf.layers.batch_normalization()` to the function?

Comment: @anand_v.singh yes, and the function also contains minus `moving_mean` and divide `moving_variance`.

Answer (score 0):

To merge two layers, you will need to pass a Tensor and get a tensor back that is after both the layers are applied, suppose your input tensor is X.

```
def MlConvBnScale(X ,kernel,strides , padding = 'SAME' , scale = False, beta_initializer = 0.1, gamma_initializer = 0.1, moving_mean_initializer = 0.1, moving_variance_initializer = 0.1):
    convLout = tf.nn.conv2d(X,
                           filter = Kernel, 
                           strides = strides,
                           padding = padding)
    return tf.nn.batch_normalization(convLout,
                                     scale = scale,
                                     beta_initializer = beta_initializer, 
                                     gamma_initializer = gamma_initializer,
                                     moving_mean_initializer = moving_mean_intializer, 
                                     moving_variance_initializer = moving_variance_initializer )
```

And that will return a tensor after performing both the operations, I have taken default values of variables but you can modify them in your function call, and in case your input is not already a tensor but a numpy array you can use `tf.convert_to_tensor()`  from this link https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/convert_to_tensor, and in case you are struggling with kernel/filter and its application, check out this thread. [What does tf.nn.conv2d do in tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34619177/what-does-tf-nn-conv2d-do-in-tensorflow)

If you have any queries or run into trouble implementing it, comment down below and we will see.

Comment: thanks for your advise, but I do mean this. I mean `merge conv layer and bn layer to one conv layer` and we need to surgery the graph and parameter. The similar method can refer to https://tkv.io/posts/fusing-batchnorm-and-conv/ and https://github.com/sanghoon/pva-faster-rcnn/commit/39570aab8c6513f0e76e5ab5dba8dfbf63e9c68c/

Comment: So you want these equations filter weights: \mathbf{W}=\mathbf{W}_{BN}\cdot \mathbf{W}_{conv}W=W 
BN
​  ⋅W 
conv
​  ;
bias: \mathbf{b}=\mathbf{W}_{BN}\cdot\mathbf{b}_{conv}+\mathbf{b}_{BN}b=W 
BN
​  ⋅b 
conv
​  +b 
BN
​  . Implemented by a function?

Comment: yes, surgery of  my pre-trained ckpt and meta file for merging bn layer into previous conv layer.